# Unusual javascript behavior

Tags: javascript

I have encountered a weird behavior in javascript. Consider this code:

```js
var foo;
function bar(){
    function foo(){};
    foo = 10;
    return;
}
foo = 1;
bar();
console.log(foo);
```

This will output 1. But if I delete the foo function declaration in the third line, it will output 10. Why isn't it output 10 when the function declaration is there? And what is the reason for if I change that function definition to this:

```
foo = function(){};
```

it will output 10 again? I know about the hoisting of function declarations, but it doesn't seem to be answer to this.

Comment: When you do `function foo(){}` this redeclare a name `foo` inside the current scope of the function and hide the global one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not weird - you have a variable called `foo`, which you're setting to 1 normally. Inside the `bar` function, the `foo` function

- if present, shadows this variable
- if not present, `foo` references this original variable.

As such, if you define that foo function, `foo=10` will take effect on that, otherwise it will take effect on the original foo.

As for the second part of the question (why does it change back if you use `var foo=...`), that's because in that case the duplicate variable declaration is merged into one, so you end up with the same as if you didn't write `var`.

Comment: Sorry, I edited, I didn't want to duplicate the declaration.
I didn't know that the function declaration shadows the global variable in stead of overwrite that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping problem. The first `foo` defined with a var is a "global" variable. When you have the `foo` function which is also a "variable" inside of the `bar` function, the `foo` assignment to 10 will be done to the local scope thus the global `foo` that you actually print out will not be changed. However, when there is no local `foo` the assignment inside of `bar` will change the global variable thus printing 10